# Converting Declaractive PrincipalPermission to Programmatic .Demand

Tags: asp.net, wcf, security, principalpermission

I currently have two roles like this:

> [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,
>   Role="Domain\Admin")]
>   [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,
>   Role="Domain\AnotherRole")]

The problem is that this inherited code is specific to the domain, and I want to eventually get the roles from the web.config file, so I can work on a VM not in the domain.

I have seen an example like this:

> ```
> PrincipalPermission permCheck = new PrincipalPermission(
>                                      null, 
>                                      @"Domain\Admin"); 
> permCheck.Demand();
> ```

Since this throws an exception if user is not in role, how do I change this example to allow either of the two roles?  I could use multiple IPrincipal.IsInRole() and then throw my own exception, but seems like there is probably a way to use the .Demand method with multiple roles.

***Update 12/21: Sample Code based on Union link from Ladislav's answer below:***

```
PrincipalPermission ppAdmin = new PrincipalPermission(null, @"Domain\Admin");
PrincipalPermission ppAnother = new PrincipalPermission(null, @"Domain\AnotherRole");
(ppAdmin.Union(ppAnother)).Demand();
```

But AzMan (suggested by Ladislav looks like a better but more involved solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrincipalPermission has [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermission.union.aspx) method. This method allows you combining several PrincipalPermissions before you call Demand. But instead of using imperative permissions you can check [Authorization manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897401.aspx) (AzMan) and related role provider ([AuthorizationStoreRoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.authorizationstoreroleprovider.aspx)). Authorization manager allows you defining abstract roles in your application and assign real user groups and roles through MMC.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the original question with a sample of the "Union" from the web page you linked me to.  AzMan also looks very cool, but will take more approval and politics.

Comment: AzMan is deprecated as of Windows Server 2012 R2 and may be removed in subsequent versions